# Blocking Or NonBlocking - Adding Element during Rehashing in HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, blocking, nonblocking

As given in documentation of HashMap when HashMap is full by 75%, HashMap internally performs rehashing of all existing objects.

If while performing rehashing, any element is added ->

- Do we have blocking behavior of HashMap ? - Means rehashing will finish first, then element will be added.

Or

- Do we have non-blocking behavior of HashMap - Means rehashing will allow adding of element in between rehashing process.

How does HashMap handles adding new element while rehashing is going on ?

Comment: How would you even know the difference between the two behaviors? You add an element, and when `HashMap.put(...)` returns the element has been added or an exception has been thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

You must apply external synchronization; otherwise the state of the map may get corrupted in the face of access by multiple threads.

If you are synchronizing, no other element can be added while the map is rearranging itself.

If you are not synchronizing, you are not using the class as documented, so the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: It was clear to me that he was asking about something else, but since he accepted your answer I don't know what to think.

Comment: @JamesKPolk what do you think he was asking about? Besides, there is nothing to stop you adding an answer, and OP deciding to accept that instead.

Comment: I thought he was asking about the internal functioning of HashMap. And I can't answer because I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not blocking, but it won't "allow adding of element in between rehashing process' either. `java.util.HashMap` is documented to be thread unsafe. If you try to add or remove on the map while it's rehashing, you will get inconsistent behaviors.

You might want to consider using `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`.